# How can i get element in string by Linq

Tags: linq

I need some help from Everyone

I have a string: "123456"

how can i get seperately "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"  by using Linq?

Tks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var str = "123456";
var digits = str.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"123456".First()
```

Also, you have the option to include a predicate function. For example,

```
"123456".First(n => n > '1')
```

But you may consider using the foreach statement instead. I'm not sure if that is considered part of LINQ though.

Comment: First phrase will give you '1'. The second will give you '2'.

Comment: Right. I probably should have mentioned that. You will be working with only one element after **.First()** is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if you want it as a LINQ query:

```
IEnumerable<string> query =
    from c in "123456"
    select c.ToString();
```

If you're happy to have an enumerable of characters you could just do this:

```
IEnumerable<char> query =
    from c in "123456"
    select c;
```